# VBA Macro - Receiving Offset Object Defined Error

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to loop through the rows in a column of a spreadsheet in which there is a time in column 1, a date in column 2, and a value in column 3. the value changes every now and then and I need to single the times out that the value was changed. I have the following code which gives me a
(run time error 1004- application defined or object defined error) and highlites

> ```
>       activecell.offset(-1,0).Range("A1").select
> ```

I have been trying to fix it/research the problem most of the afternoon but can't get an answer that works for me. any help would be appreciated

```
Sub Timestamp

    Range("C1").Select

    While ActiveCell.Value <> ""

        Number = ActiveCell.Value
        Counter = Counter +1
        activecell.offset(-1,0).Range("A1").select 

        If ActiveCell.Value <> Number Then

            activecell.offset(-1,0).Range("A1").select 
            Time = ActiveCell.Value
            Sample = Sample +1
            activecell.offset((Counter - Sample),3).Range("A1").select 
            ActiveCell.Value = Time
            activecell.offset(-(Counter - Sample),-1).Range("A1").select 

        End If
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: You're in the first row (C1) and so can't offset one row up (negative = up). But there's no need to `Select` or use `ActiveCell`.

Comment: thanx, I just realised now how simple that was. not the first time I forget negative is up. really appreciate the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to select the cells to get their values. All you need is to refer to them.  VBA is an Object Oriented programming language. Take a look at this document for basics:
[Object Oriented VBA](https://pages.uoregon.edu/pangburn/dsc340notes/VBA.pdf)

As far as getting a count of the times the Number changes, this should give you that value and you can add in any additional code you need to be handling.

```
    Option Explicit

Sub test()
Dim rng As Range
Dim number As Long
Dim counter As Integer

    Set rng = Range("C1")
    Do While rng.Value <> ""
        number = rng.Value
        If rng.Offset(1, 0).Value <> number Then
            counter = counter + 1
        End If
    Set rng = rng.Offset(1, 0)
    Loop
    MsgBox counter & " changes"
End Sub
```

Comment: awesome. thanx a lot for the advise

Comment: You're welcome. If don't mind, could you upvote/accept the answer?